# ....com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception:.AAPT2 error:check logs for details

Tags: android

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

Answer (score 1):

It will happen, if your one of paths contains non-ASCII or ' ' (space) character. 
Try to change your service directory path to: `C:/Users/Public/.gradle` in `Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Gradle`

Answer (score 0):

If you're in Ionic, there might be missing configurations from config.xml to your android platform. In my case was `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` missing in app/src/main/res/xml/config.xml and in AndroidManifest.xml